# Vim spell check automatically splits the screen

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I typed `z=` underneath a misspelled word, and vim split the screen horizontally, thereby keeping the misspelled word in context, but also providing a list words to change the misspelled word from. Usually, this latter screen replaces the former screen when I hit `z=`.

I like this behavior, but can not replicate it. I must have hit something before `z=` but I do not know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you saw *accidentally* happens when there are only a few suggestions and they don't fill the entire window.
You can force a maximum size for the suggestion list (example: 20 suggestions) with

```
set spellsuggest=best,20
```

Now, as long as your window exceeds 20 lines, you will see the misspelled word in context, and the bottom 20 lines of your window filled with the suggestion list

Comment: 6 years after I ask the question, I have resolution! I just added this to my .vimrc. It's exactly what I was asking for!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what caused the behavior you saw, maybe it is some plugin.
But here are two options to stay in the context with spellchecker:

1) Use `CTRL-X s` in insert mode:

> In Insert mode, when the cursor is after a badly spelled word, you can use
>   CTRL-X s to find suggestions.  This works like Insert mode completion.  Use
>   CTRL-N to use the next suggestion, CTRL-P to go back. |i_CTRL-X_s|

2) Use [vimple](https://github.com/dahu/vimple) plugin which turns few full-screen windows (including spell suggestions) into "overlays" (actually split windows where you can select the word you need).